# read MS Word in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I want to read the MS Word in ASP.NET C#. I want to print text of word file in a Textbox. and  index or headings of document data in other Textbox. 
I searched so may forums but did not get the answer which is providing a free api to do this task.

Please provide a sample code to accomplish this task.

Comment: Do you have to support older versions of Word? (As in before 2007?) If not, you should look into the xml format they introduced, and do simple xml parsing to extract the stuff you need. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Have you done any search on google ?

Comment: yes i search from google

Comment: http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com

Answer (score 0):

If Word is installed on your machine, then you already have the API you need. See the following documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726434

As far as code samples go, your question is too broad and you haven't shown any work.